# The REST API call gave the following unexpected result: (500) ** i use google cloud server

Tags: wordpress, rest, elementor

The REST API is one way WordPress, and other applications, communicate with the server. One example is the block editor screen, which relies on this to display, and save, your posts and pages.

The REST API call gave the following unexpected result: (500)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
            <meta name='robots' content='max-image-preview:large, noindex, follow' />
            <title>WordPress › Error</title>
            <style type="text/css"> html { background: #f1f1f1; } body { background: #fff; border: 1px solid #ccd0d4; color: #444; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen-Sans, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif; margin: 2em auto; padding: 1em 2em; max-width: 700px; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .04); box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .04); } h1 { border-bottom: 1px solid #dadada; clear: both; color: #666; font-size: 24px; margin: 30px 0 0 0; padding: 0; padding-bottom: 7px; } #error-page { margin-top: 50px; } #error-page p, #error-page .wp-die-message { font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.5; margin: 25px 0 20px; } #error-page code { font-family: Consolas, Monaco, monospace; } ul li { margin-bottom: 10px; font-size: 14px ; } a { color: #0073aa; } a:hover, a:active { color: #006799; } a:focus { color: #124964; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #5b9dd9, 0 0 2px 1px rgba(30, 140, 190, 0.8); box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #5b9dd9, 0 0 2px 1px rgba(30, 140, 190, 0.8); outline: none; } .button { background: #f3f5f6; border: 1px solid #016087; color: #016087; display: inline-block; text-decoration: none; font-size: 13px; line-height: 2; height: 28px; margin: 0; padding: 0 10px 1px; cursor: pointer; -webkit-border-radius: 3px; -webkit-appearance: none; border-radius: 3px; white-space: nowrap; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; vertical-align: top; } .button.button-large { line-height: 2.30769231; min-height: 32px; padding: 0 12px; } .button:hover, .button:focus { background: #f1f1f1; } .button:focus { background: #f3f5f6; border-color: #007cba; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #007cba; box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #007cba; color: #016087; outline: 2px solid transparent; outline-offset: 0; } .button:active { background: #f3f5f6; border-color: #7e8993; -webkit-box-shadow: none; box-shadow: none; } </style>
        </head>
        <body id="error-page">
            <div class="wp-die-message">
                <p>There has been a critical error on this website.</p>
                <p>
                    <a href="https://wordpress.org/support/article/faq-troubleshooting/">Learn more about troubleshooting WordPress.</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html> .
```

Comment: There is a critical/fatal error on the website. If its your website you will likely want to enable error reporting and see whats causing the issue. We cannot answer this based on current information

Answer (score -2):

I checked codes in *EDIT THEME* in functions and it solved .

Comment: Please add more information to your answer, what code you changed and how it fixed your problem.